# How linux use as a switch with 802.1Q

Tags: ubuntu, switch-statement, trunk

How can I use a Ubuntu server as a switch.

I tested interface configured with vlan and ip address which work properly. But how can I make 2 different interface in a same vlan and the other device can ping through ubutu server.

The topology should be here.

sw1==Trunk==Server Eth1.100====Server Eth2.100==Trunk==Sw2.

I have searched a lot of document but didn't find a particular one can solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is off-topic anyway, since it isn't a programming question.